# What's the necessary and sufficient condition for gauge equivalence in the projective construction?

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

The definition of  *gauge equivalence* and notations used here is the same as those in my [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86841/some-questions-on-the-wilson-loop-in-the-projective-construction).

As we know, the condition $\chi_{ij}'=G_i\chi_{ij}G_j^\dagger$(where $G_i\in SU(2)$) is a *sufficient condition* for the $H$ and $H'$ being gauge equivalent, but is it also a *necessary condition*? If not, then what's the *necessary and sufficient condition* for gauge equivalence? Is my [conjecture (1)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/86841/some-questions-on-the-wilson-loop-in-the-projective-construction) correct?

Thanks in advance.